# Swapping columns in vi with regex without using awk, read, etc

Tags: regex, bash, shell, multiple-columns, vi

I have a file of 1000 lines, with 5 to 8 columns in each line separated by `:`

```
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8

4g10:8s:45:9u5b:a:z1
```

I want to have all lines in some order `4:3:1:2:5:6:7...`

How would I swap only first 4 columns with regex?

Comment: Not clear, please put more sample Input_file and expected output too in your post with code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would probably be easier to do with another approach, but you could use `ex` to do it, so be in command mode and enter:

```
:%s/^\([^:]\+\):\([^:]\+\):\([^:]\+\):\([^:]\+\):/\4:\3:\1:\2:/
```

which will create capture groups for the first 4 colon delimited fields, then replace them in a different order than they were there originally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that should do what you are looking for:

```
newtext = re.sub("([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)(:)?(.*)?",r"\4:\3:\1:\2\5\6",text)
```

The take away is you'll want to use parans for capturing and then reorder them in the order you want them in the replace.  Each capture "group" is just one or more non : separated by :   If there is possibility of empty groups change each + to a *

Here is a sample in Python for clarity:

```
import re

textlist = [
"1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8",
"1:2:3:4:5",
"1:2:3:4",
]


for text in textlist:
    newtext = re.sub("([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+):([^:]+)(:)?(.*)?",r"\4:\3:\1:\2\5\6",text)
    print (newtext)
```

output:

```
4:3:1:2:5:6:7:8
4:3:1:2:5
4:3:1:2
```